# ¿Cómo importo funciones de un .ipynb a otro .ipynb en Google COLAB?

Tags: python, google-colab

Estoy empezando a trabajar en Google COLAB y tengo la necesidad de importar funciones que diseñé en otro archivo .ipynb y .py al archivo .ipynb donde trabajo, al inicio intenté hacerlo como trabajaba de forma local en Spyder (Tener el archivo donde contenía las funciones que diseñé y el archivo donde trabajaba en la misma carpeta), sin embargo esta lógica no me rinde frutos en Google COLAB.

¿Existe alguna manera de solucionar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo siguiendo los siguientes pasos:

1. Utiliza el [montaje automático](https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1226929213560610818?s=20) de Google Colab
2. Instalamos `kora` para importar `drive` y llamar al método `link_nbs()`

```
!pip install kora -q
from kora import drive
drive.link_nbs()
```

3. Ya puedes realizar importaciones desde cualquier otro Notebook.

```
#ejemplo
from mynotebook import formula1
```

Comment: asociada https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59020008/how-to-import-functions-of-a-jupyter-notebook-into-another-jupyter-notebook-in-g